# Road surface roughness

Tags: data-request, geospatial, openstreetmap

Is there some open data about road surface roughness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Italy there is a project named SmartRoadSense, started on February 21th, 2015. The goal of this project is monitoring of Italy's road surface (487,700 km [1]) and all results are open data.

Now, after nine months, has been collected more than 24,000 km of open data. In the site [smartroadsense.it](http://smartroadsense.it/) you can see two uses of this data, and donwload it.

The project use a simple Android application that senses the roughness via LPC coding (for more detail read the paper [SmartRoadSense: Collaborative Road Surface Condition Monitoring](http://bit.do/srs-uniurb)). In the roadmap there is also the development of the application for the others platform.

You can see a short movie which showing the four phases of the SmartRoadSense process: sampling, map matching, aggregation, and presentation [here](https://youtu.be/xdWODlEXXGg).

The data are available at [smartroadsense.it](http://smartroadsense.it/open-data.html). You find an only CSV file with six fields:

- LATITUDE
- LONGITUDE
- PPE, roughness value in this path
- OSM_ID, ID of the road in OpenStreetMap
- HIGHWAY, category of the road in OpenStreetMap
- UPDATED_AT, date of the last update of this roughness

---

[1] "*Italy.*" The World Factbook. Central Intelligence Agency, 2013.

Comment: Rewrite your question so that it reads more like a question someone would ask. "Where can I obtain data about Italian road surface roughness?" Omit the material about your project. Perhaps include some information about why a person might be seeking this data. Your answer as it is is pretty good: complete and concise. You might also move some of the explanation from the question there if you think it helps. Then, best practice when self-answering questions is to check the "community wiki" button to make it clear that you aren't answering your own question just to inflate your reputation.

Comment: Ok @JoeGermuska, and sorry me.

Comment: Thanks! I see now my comment might have been brusque: didn't mean to be, but there was a maximum character limit.

Comment: Interesting project.  (and one of my pet peeves).  Is there any chance of using this to get road conditions for other countries, too?  (I'm thinking that this could be great for local governments to see which roads need to be resurfaced and/or potholes filled, not just as a warning for motorists to avoid roads on trips)

Comment: @Joe - In a future. In this moment, the project is only for Italy because the University of Urbino is in Italy. You can easily understand that a mapping of whole planet need a big server, and of a big data processing that a single university do not has.

Answer (score 3):

The international version of SmartRoadSense will be announced today during a press conference in Urbino (Italy). 
http://smartroadsense.it/blog/en/crowd4roads-the-european-project/